# Geometric Coupon Payment

Tags: finance

> An investor owns a bond that is redeemable for 250 in 6 years from now. The investor has just received a coupon of $c$ and each subsequent semiannual coupon will be 2% larger than the preceding coupon. The present value of this bond immediately after the payment of the coupon is 582.53 assuming an annual effective yield rate of 4%.
>   Calculate $c$.

My Solution: First, I converted the effective rate of interest $i$ to nominal rate compounded semianually, which is $$1.04 = (1+j)^2 \Rightarrow j=1.09804$$I really think that the first coupon payment was $c$, followed by $c(1.02)$, $c(1.02)^2,...,c(1.02)^{11}$, hence having the equation
$$582.53 = cv + c(1.02)v^2 +...+c(1.02)^{11}v^{12} + 250v^{12}$$
$$\Rightarrow 582.53 = cv(1+1.02v +(1.02v)^2+...+(1.02v)^{11}) + 250v^{12}$$
$$\Rightarrow 582.53 = cv\left[\dfrac{1-(1.02v)^{12}}{1-1.02v}\right] + 250v^{12}$$ 
$$\Rightarrow c = 32.68$$

> SOA solution: It appears that the FIRST coupon payment was $c(1.02)$, hence the equation
>   $$582.53 = c(1.02)v + c(1.02v)^2 +...+c(1.02v)^{12} + 250v^{12}$$
>   $$\Rightarrow c=32.04$$

By the way, both answers are in the multiple choice. My question is, why is it that the first payment is $c(1.02)$? As far as I know, "the investor received a coupon of c, and each subsequent semiannual coupon will be $2\%$ larger", hence I really thought my equation was correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"The investor has **just** received a coupon of $c$ and each subsequent semiannual coupon will be $2\%$ larger than the preceding coupon."*  So $c$ was in the past, and the first in the future will be $c(1.02)$

Comment: Wow, never would I have seen the word "just" if you haven't mentioned it. Thank You!

Comment: I'm confused with the solution. Since the question mention after the first coupon payment, so there should be only 11 coupon payment left with. But why the last coupon payment is discounted by 12 but not 11 ?